# Raneto on apache virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, node.js

I just installed Raneto (http://www.raneto.com) which uses nodejs
and it listens on port 3000 and i can only view the webpages when i run `npm start` and go to http://server-ip:3000 while the session (npm start) is still on

What i want to do is have the raneto be served permanently on a virtual host on apache.
There is no where in documentation mentioning how to do this

So need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The way to run raneto permanently is by using the forever package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Can you set your answer as solved ? thanks